# Absolutely positioned elements within inline-block

Tags: absolute, css

I've run into an issue while trying to bottom-align a logo container to the zero-height parent. Preferably, I want to achieve this with pure CSS.

In the attached fiddle, I want to get the bottom of the `control-group` to be aligned to the top of the zero-height `panel` element. The markup needs to stay the way it is. Is it possible to do this without specifying static height or top offset? The parent needs to be zero-heght. Otherwise, if its above the content and it will have height, it will overlap the light-blue container, which will have other content. As such, content in the blue div will not be clickable in the part that is overlapped by the `panel` div. Any suggestions?

The problem can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jQgHy/5/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for...

```
.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jQgHy/6/

Comment: Not quite. I've tried absolutely positioning the element but it throws off the centering. You can open up chrome dev tools, toggle on/off the position:absolute property, and see that the logo shifts slightly.

Comment: I did see that for sure, but the general position is that where you wanted?

Comment: Yep, the general position is correct, except for the centering.

Comment: sadly I'm not sure how to get the centering right .. I see what you're attempting, but I can't think of a universal way. I'm sorry :(